# Python asyncio program does not exit waiting for stdin input

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a complex Python 3.9 program that does not exit if interrupted with Ctrl-C (SIGINT). The following is a minimal repro of the problem. Run with `python sample.py` You should see two prompts for input, then a normal exit. If you hit Ctrl-C on the first prompt, it exits as expected. If you hit Ctrl-C on the second prompt, nothing happens, until you hit Enter (and then an uncaught KeyboardInterrupt happens deep inside selectors.py).

```py
import asyncio

async def ainput(prompt: str = "") -> str:
    return await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, input, prompt)

async def main():
    try:
        input("1>")             # ctrl-C here works as expected, prints the message and exits
        await ainput("2>")      # ctrl-C here does nothing until you hit Enter
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ctrl-C")

asyncio.run(main())
```

#### Question

Is this a bug in the code above? Or a bug in asyncio? How can I fix this?

#### Output

```
$ python sample.py
1>asks
2>lsls
$ python sample.py
1>^CCtrl-C
$ python sample.py
1>slsl
2>^C # **nothing happens here until you hit Enter**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/work/experimental/sample.py", line 15, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/alexa/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/alexa/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 634, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/alexa/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/alexa/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1869, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/alexa/lib/python3.9/selectors.py", line 562, in select
    kev_list = self._selector.control(None, max_ev, timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  The issue is that you're running `input` in a separate thread.  When you press Ctrl-C, Python delivers the `KeyboardInterrupt` to the main thread only.  Unfortunately, I'm a newbie to `asyncio` myself and don't know the right way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. How can I receive that exception and cancel all tasks?  I tried to capture SIGINT with loop.add_signal_handler and that also doesn't work (meaning, the handler is called, I then cancelled all tasks, but the program never exits despite all my code paths reaching their last line).

Comment: A relevant section in the docs is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown). Specifically:
*Regardless of the value of wait, the entire Python program will not exit until all pending futures are done executing.*
This may indicate it is not possible to cancel an `input()` future once it is started this way. It completes with the Enter key, then the program can exit.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is the `KeyboardInterrupt` is caught by `asyncio` since you are using `threading`. What `asyncio` then does is feed this into your coroutine by attempting to cancel it, which raises `asyncio.CancelledError`. You can handle it like this:

```py
async def main():
    try:
        input("1>")
        await ainput("2>")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Ctrl-C")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Cancelled?")
        raise
```

There isn't any way to stop `asyncio.run(...)` from raising the `KeyboardInterrupt` however, at least AFAIK.